# How to use a variable in a regular expression in Octave?

Tags: octave

I have the following regular expression:

```
>> str = 'aaabbbaaa';
>> regexp(str, '^a+')
ans = 1
```

How do I use a variable in the pattern for the regular expression? Something like the following:

```
>> str = 'aaabbbaaa';
>> searchchar = 'a'
>> regexp(str, '^searchchar')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to insert the value of the variable into a string. One way is concatenating characters:

```matlab
str = 'aaabbbaaa';
searchchar = 'a'
expr = ['^',searchchar,'+'];
regexp(str, expr)
```

A different way is to use `sprintf` to build the expression string:

```matlab
expr = sprintf('^%s+',searchchar);
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this with a string concatenation:

```
>> str = 'aaabbbaaa'
>> searchchar = 'a'
>> regexp(str, cstrcat('^', searchchar, '+'))
ans = 1
```